# Golang - AES-128-CBC Decryption returns invalid/strange characters before decrypted message

Tags: go, aes, cbc-mode

I'm trying to decrypt aes-128-cbc data using go.

Everything seams to working, but i getting random text with invalid/strange characters before decrypted message.

Here is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/sha512"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/hkdf"
)

func main() {
    encryptedData := "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"
    key := getHKDF()
    decryptedData := Decrypt(encryptedData, key)
    fmt.Printf("%s", decryptedData)

}

func getHKDF() []byte {
    hash := sha512.New
    secret := []byte("MY SECRET")
    salt := []byte("")
    if _, err := rand.Read(salt); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    info := []byte("MY INOF")

    kdf := hkdf.New(hash, secret, salt, info)

    key := make([]byte, 16)
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(kdf, key); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return key
}

func Decrypt(encryptedData string, key []byte) []byte {
    data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encryptedData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    iv := data[0:aes.BlockSize]

    buffer := make([]byte, len(data)-len(iv))
    decrypter := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)

    decrypter.CryptBlocks(buffer, data[len(iv):])
    return PKCS7Unpadding(buffer)
}

func PKCS7Unpadding(plantText []byte) []byte {
    length := len(plantText)
    padding := int(plantText[length-1])
    return plantText[:(length - padding)]
}
```

Output

```
`����G�_Qf2�mr�w\yX�yN^|��-2�Dw,��z�N�����DsG
������%�I���
��O�اP��}���H��w���G�X�g6�S|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
```

A quick fix for it is remove all text before last pipe (|)

Example

```
fmt.Printf("%s", decryptedData[strings.LastIndex(string(decryptedData), "|")+1:])
```

Output

```
YToxNjp7czoyOiJpZCI7aTo0NTg7czo3OiJwcm9kdWN0IjtzOjQwOiJBcnRpY2Egc29mdHdhcmUgMSB5ZWFyIExpY2Vuc2UgMC01IFVzZXJzIjtzOjY6ImV4cGlyZSI7czoxMDoiNDA3MDk5NTE0MCI7czoxMDoibWF4X3NlcnZlciI7czoxOiI0IjtzOjEwOiJzZWxsZXJfY2lkIjtpOjI1O3M6MTA6InNlbGxlcl91aWQiO2k6ODE7czoxMDoiY29tcGFueV9pZCI7aToxMzk7czo0OiJwYWlkIjtpOjE7czo2OiJzZWxsZXIiO3M6MzM6IkFuZHLDqSBCb2xpbmhhcyBAIFNBUyBBcnRpY2EgVGVjaCI7czo2OiJhY3RpdmUiO2k6MTtzOjU6ImxhYmVsIjtzOjg6Im15X2xhYmVsIjtzOjc6InNlcnZpY2UiO2k6MTtzOjEyOiJtYXhfd2Vic2l0ZXMiO047czoxMjoiY29tcGFueV9uYW1lIjtzOjEwOiJSb2RyaWd1ZXphIjtzOjk6IlgtQVBJLUtFWSI7czozMjoiNDAxYTk0ZWQ2MjFlZWZmOWY1OGE2N2MxY2Q1YzJkZTgiO3
```

Anyone can help to figure out resolve this issue properly without the need to removing unnecessary parts of the decoded message or to check if my decryption fuction is correct?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: Neither of the two posted outputs can be reconstructed with the posted code: https://go.dev/play/p/J8Mtd89DsAQ. Please double check your data and post consistent data.

Comment: Regarding the ciphertext: The first 64 bytes seem to be hex encoded, the rest seems to be Base64 encoded. To determine the meaning of both parts, you need to know the encryption code! Otherwise it can only be guessed. Thus post the encryption code.

Comment: @Topaco, I have deleted some sensitive information on my example, like the key, info and part of decoded message. The base64 encoded message is ok and is the correct decrypted data, my question is why i get the first 64 bytes in hex encoded and how to remove it. If you want i can create a working example for you. Thanks

Comment: Yes, post consistent data that can be decrypted with the code in the way you described. As I said, the most important thing would be to also post the encryption code (in addition to consistent data).

Comment: Regarding your question: *... my question is why i get the first 64 bytes in hex encoded...*. Since there are countless ways to encrypt data, only the encryption code can answer this question. Possibly the hex encoded part is related to the key derivation via HKDF, e.g. the salt, but this is pure speculation.

Comment: @Topaco, i will create a working example for you.

Comment: @Topaco, thanks for your help, after analyzing seams that the first 64bytes have a second encryptation for authentication propose, so i had to decrypt first only the first 64bytes using correct key and than the remaning bytes using a secondary key. Now is all working fine. Thanks